# Example: Dirac function in two dimensions.

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

I am considering an equation of the form $$\int_{\mathbb{R}^{2}} f(x) \delta(s - x \cdot \theta)dx$$

where $\delta$ is a two-dimensional Dirac function. What does this evaluate to, exactly? I know that if we instead had

$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^{2}} f(x) \delta(s - x)dx$$

then this would evaluate to $f(s)$. But what effect does the dot product have on this evaluation?

Comment: Heuristically it is a weighted sum of the values of $f$ on $\{ x : x \cdot \theta = s \}$. This set in this case is the line $x_1 \theta_1 + x_2 \theta_2 = s$ (in higher dimensions it would be a hyperplane). Identifying the weight is the tricky part.

Comment: Thanks a lot! The particular problem I'm working on has $\theta = (-\sin\theta, \cos\theta)$. Not sure if that makes it straightforward to identify the weight.

Comment: Another way to think about this is that your integral is over the surface measure for the line. The question is which multiple of the usual surface measure (i.e. length) is it. In this case I think it is just the usual one, since $\| \theta \| = 1$.

Comment: This is just a Radon transform. See Wikipedia for more info, and a plethora of properties and reconstruction algorithms, such as filtered backprojection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, let's clear up some potential meaning confusion.  In the equation
$$\int_{\Bbb{R}^2} g(\vec{x}) \delta(\vec{y}-\vec{x}) dx = g(\vec{y}) $$
the nature of $g(x)$ is $g : \Bbb{R}^2 \mapsto \Bbb{R}$.
 But in the expression
$$\int_{\Bbb{R}^2} f(\vec{x}) \delta(\vec{s}-\vec{x} \cdot \vec{\theta}) dx  $$
the nature of $f(x)$ is $f: \Bbb{R} \mapsto \Bbb{R}$,
that is, $f(x)$ is a mapping taking a *scalar* into a scalar, not a vector into a scalar.

Now to get the answer.  Say we rotate our coordinate variables, to a frame where $\vec{\theta} = p \hat{x}'$. The Hessian of this transformation is one, and in the new coordinates 
$\vec{x} \cdot \vec{\theta} = p x'$.
So the integral becomes
$$
\int_{y' = -\infty}^{\infty} \int_{x' = -\infty}^{\infty} f(x',y') \delta(s-px') dx \, dy 
= \int_{y' = -\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{p} f(\frac{s}{p},y') dy
$$
Now we want to go back to the original frame, but again since the rotation did not change any scales, one unit of distance along $y'$ is the same as one unit of distance along the line $\vec{x}\cdot\vec{\theta} = s$.  So if we let $\hat{u}$ be a unit vector parallel to $\theta$, and take $\vec{x}_0$ to be any point along  $\vec{x}_0 \cdot \vec{\theta} = s$, we will be able to express the line integral as an integral along points of the form $\vec{x}_0 + t\hat{u}$ with unit distance scaling.

So, using the fact that $p = |\vec{\theta}|$, the answer is the line integral
$$
\frac{1}{|\vec{\theta}|}\int_{t=-\infty}^\infty f(\vec{x}_0 + t\hat{u})\, dt
$$
The important non-trivial thing to note is that the weighting along the line does not depend on the value or the derivatives of the function $f$.